# Flutter text aligment

Tags: flutter, text-alignment

I'm using row to display this text. But when I use expanded widget to make multiline the second text (e.g. AMD Ryzen… / 30 days...) then the first text (e.g. Processor/OS) becomes vertical center, I want that vertical top. I tried few widgets like align, etc. but didn't worked.

Code:

```
Widget _specificationRow(String title, String description) {
  return new Row(children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Text(
          '• $title :',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              fontSize: 15.0,
              fontFamily: "GoogleSans"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Text(
          '$description',
          maxLines: 3,
          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15.0,
              fontFamily: "GoogleSans"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                '• title : ',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontFamily: "GoogleSans"),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'sfdadfafdsfseriewhfkjsvk shfhskdfhs sdfsd fyesruwefkj\nsdfassdfsafdsafd',
                  maxLines: 3,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontFamily: "GoogleSans"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

please provide `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`

[image]